# GDAL python package with Anaconda and ElasticSearch 7

Tags: python, gdal, anaconda, conda, elasticsearch

I'm trying to import feature data into elasticsearch v7.4 using GDAL to convert from an ArcGIS feature service layer into geoJSON for indexing.

We use anaconda 3 (latest version 2019.10) for our python environment. When you pull GDAL it seems to be pinned back at version 2.3.3 - despite being up to version  3.0.x on conda-forge.

Unfortunately only version >= 2.4 of GDAL works with ElasticSearch > 2.

I've tried switching to the conda-forge channel but incompatibilities make my environment unresolvable.

I've tried using pip instead but it's getting complicated as it requires MS Build tools as it's trying to build from source versions.

I've managed to make it work as a proof of concept using a GDAL docker image but I need to productionise this with Anaconda.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: This is pretty much a pure conda problem. For it to be solved someone attempting an answer would need to know your full requirements list (with version dependencies), the environment you are running it in as well as the allowed repositories you can use and/or the build tools you have available.